# exclude multiple directories from find result

Tags: bash, find

I need to exclude multiple directories from find result. I know how to do it by hard coding in the `find` command, but can it be possible to store the list of excluded dir as a variable or array and later used in find command ?

Here is my working command: In this command, I am `touching` a file called `dumped` inside all the directories in the current directories with `maxdepth 1` except `.` , `./tmp` , `./garbage` directories.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path "." ! -path "./tmp" ! -path "./garbage" -type d -exec touch {}/dumped  2>/dev/null \;
```

If you notice I have provided hard coding in the `find` command for the directories  to be excluded.

If there any way to store the list in a variable and pass to the `find` command ?

something like `exclude_list=".|./tmp|./garbage"` and use it afterwards ?

I tried following but it did not worked:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path ${exclude_list}
```

Comment: you may use `find ..... |grep -Ev './tmp|....'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested: use an array

```
find_clauses=(
      -maxdepth 1 
    ! -path "." 
    ! -path "./tmp" 
    ! -path "./garbage" 
      -type d 
      -exec touch {}/dumped ';'
)
find . "${find_clauses[@]}" 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to put the excluded directories in a list, you can still build the find clauses dynamically:

```
exclude_dirs=( . ./tmp ./garbage )

find_clauses=( -maxdepth 1 )
for d in "${exclude_dirs[@]}"; do find_clauses+=( ! -path "$d" ); done
find_clauses+=( 
      -type d 
      -exec touch {}/dumped ';'
)

find . "${find_clauses[@]}" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: thanks you Glenn , is there any way to make this work in Makefile ? its failing in makefile , but running in normal shell

Comment: Don't know. Add an appropriate tag to your question and mention Makefile in the question text, and perhaps a makefile expert will have a look.